# Django sites framework - Is this a good fit?

Tags: python, django, performance

I am trying to run around 50 mini sites which share about 90% of their code. My inital idea was to run them as separate applications with a common library but I have read about the sites framework which would allow them to run from a single instance.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/

My question is, is the site framework the right approach to a problem like this, and does it have real benefits over running separate applications.

Comment: IMO you didnt give enough informations what a mini site is in ur case. vote to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: A mini site is to query an API and show the results

Comment: that does not enlighten it much more.

Comment: I don't know how much more I can say. It simply queries a SOLR search server, and puts the JSON response in paginated form.

Comment: Will the 50 mini sites have their own user base? or can all user edit all sites? if it is for api only, wouldnt it be enough to distinguish the different data sets by some sort of unique api key?

Comment: Each site will be on it's own domain, and have a different style.css and config.py. The userbase (and the database generally) will be shared across the board.

Comment: and now u should incorporate this information into your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sites framework is likely perfect for what you are doing. Generally, it allows you to use the same architecture and functionality across a variety of extremely similar sites. The main benefit is that instead of having to manage 50 different servers, or 50 different instances of Django running, that you can maintain 1 instance of Django. That includes database migrations, deployments, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How is it in terms of performance, does it degrade the site significantly or does it maintain its performance

Answer (score 1):

The sites framework is mostly useful to implement "multi tenancy" in your database - different sets of data belonging to different sites/instances, all in the same database.
Along with this you can define a hostname for each site.

But your SITE_ID is set in settings.py, so in order to have multiple sites, you need multiple settings.py configurations, which means multiple distinct processes/instances. You can of course share the code base between them, but each site will need a dedicated worker / WSGIDaemon to serve the site.

Alternatively, you can use [django_layers](https://github.com/iivvoo/django_layers) (a package I wrote) to serve different sites (with different templates, static resources, and so on) from a single instance.